# How can one test a sewage ejector pump?

Tags: plumbing, sewer

I have a sewer ejector pump in my basement but it's in a sealed well. There are two electric cords running into it. How does one test it? For maintenance reasons. Can this only be done by a plumber?

I have a sump pump too and those are well documented on how do monthly tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sewage ejection pumps have two cords.  One is the power for the motor.  The other goes to the float switch.  The power cord is a regular plug.  The float switch cord has a plug on the end with female on one side and male on the other.  The power's plug is inserted into the female side of the float switch plug.  The male side of the float plug is then inserted into an electrical outlet.  When the water level trips the float, the float's plug "opens" to give power to the motor's cord.  If you want to test the pump manually, find the outlet the cords are plugged into, unplug the motor's plug from the float's and insert the motor's plug directly into the outlet, bypassing the float.  When you're satisfied, insert the motor's plug back into the float plug and insert the float plug back into the electrical outlet.

Comment: The working condition/s for the pump would have the pump submerged, or atleast have waste water/sludge flowing through the device as the float switch indicates. Is there any risk associated with testing the pump in a dry condition? Overheating, and such?

Comment: The pump I have is a Burcam pump. I don't think any cooling actually happens from the fluid ejected based on how it sits in the reservoir. The motor sits above the fluid level at all times. I have run mine dry several times for a few seconds when testing. What would probably overheat the motor is running it for an extended period of time, whether it's ejecting fluid or nothing at all.